# Docker file and compose update

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created a simple tech stack using Docker. PHP 7.2 on CentOS.

Below is the docker file

```
FROM centos:7

# Install Apache
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install httpd httpd-tools

# Install EPEL Repo
RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm \
 && rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm

# Install PHP
RUN yum -y install php72w php72w-bcmath php72w-cli php72w-common php72w-gd php72w-intl php72w-ldap php72w-mbstring \
    php72w-mysql php72w-pear php72w-soap php72w-xml php72w-xmlrpc

# Update Apache Configuration
RUN sed -E -i -e '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/<\/Directory>/s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN sed -E -i -e 's/DirectoryIndex (.*)$/DirectoryIndex index.php \1/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

Below is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
  services:
   centos-php-apache:
     build:
       context: ./
     ports:
      - "8080:80"
     volumes:
      - ./code:/var/www/html
```

All is now running fine. After few days, I decided to update the following -

(i) Update “dockerfile” by adding another php-module or php-extension

(ii) Update the docker compose.yml by adding another service (say) “mariadb”.

I would like to do this update, without effecting or deleting any files from the previous setup. In fact, this is a common scenario, where developers may need additional extensions or service in the future - without redoing everything right from the beginning.

Should I directly edit the "dockerfile" and add the php extension and edit the docker-compose.yml file and add the service as usual and then run the docker-compose up command. Of course before running the "up" command, I will first bring it down using the docker-compose down command.

Can anyone throw some light, on how I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

It would be best if you used `docker-compose up --build centos-php-apache` instead of `docker-compose up` . And you do not want to worry about data. They are persistent with your volume map. Also, make sure to use another volume map for your mariadb data.

Comment: What is the advantage of using this "docker-compose up --build centos-php-apache" instead of docker-compose up? Also, Volume has already been added, so why another Volume?

Comment: Q:
What is the advantage of using this "docker-compose up --build centos-php-apache" instead of docker-compose up?

A:
you need to apply your changes to the docker image. therefore you need to use it.

Q:
 Also, Volume has already been added, so why another Volume

A:
that volume makes sure to the persistence of your MariaDB database data. That is why you need another volume for MariaDB service.

Comment: Persistent data is not just from MariaDB. /code will store user uploaded images, systems generated pdf’s etc. all are persistent data. I think ./code:/var/www/html is fine and the named volume that you are mentioning will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding a dummy setup, together with the contents of the files:

```
tree
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── mariadb
│   └── Dockerfile
└── web-app
    └── Dockerfile

------------------------

cat docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./web-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  mariadb:
    build:
      context: ./mariadb
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=supersecret

------------

cat mariadb/Dockerfile 
FROM mariadb
RUN echo "hello from mariadb"

------------

cat web-app/Dockerfile 
FROM nginx
RUN echo "Hello"
RUN echo "from web-app"
# ^^ that's an example for a change that you want to perform(adding a new module) ^^
```

Assuming that you just performed the change in the web-app/Dockerfile, you have a couple of options:

**Option A:**

You rebuild one specific image, while the current containers are not affected:

```
docker-compose build webapp

Building webapp
Step 1/3 : FROM nginx
 ---> 2622e6cca7eb
Step 2/3 : RUN echo "Hello"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ad39a2920d75
Step 3/3 : RUN echo "from web-app"
 ---> Running in ea62a9e81110
from web-app
Removing intermediate container ea62a9e81110
 ---> 9fc79785a4c4
```

When you are comfortable with the image that you built, redeploy the containers that suffered image changes(note that if you run docker-compose up, only the web-app is redeployed):

```
docker-compose up -d  

stack-example_mariadb_1 is up-to-date
Recreating stack-example_webapp_1 ... done
```

**Option B:**

If your confident with the changes that you performed on the Dockerfile, go for the one-liner with the `--build` option:

```
docker-compose up -d --build 

Building webapp
Step 1/4 : FROM nginx
 ---> 2622e6cca7eb
Step 2/4 : RUN echo "Hello"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ad39a2920d75
Step 3/4 : RUN echo "from web-appi"
 ---> Running in 8cbd41c34d35
from web-appi
Removing intermediate container 8cbd41c34d35
 ---> ed7bc1950d4c
Step 4/4 : RUN echo "change 2"
 ---> Running in f52be965609f
change 2
Removing intermediate container f52be965609f
 ---> da600ed3f0ed
Successfully built da600ed3f0ed
Successfully tagged stack-example_webapp:latest
Building mariadb
Step 1/2 : FROM mariadb
 ---> 8075b7694a2d
Step 2/2 : RUN echo "hello from mariadb"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 89f75af407fe
Successfully built 89f75af407fe
Successfully tagged stack-example_mariadb:latest
Recreating stack-example_webapp_1 ... 
Recreating stack-example_webapp_1 ... done
```

Comment: Assuming, I go with Option B - but the build fails (throws some error), then what? Because, I may not be confident. the whole purpose of this command is to rebuild in detached mode. In this case it rebuilds all the services, whereas in the former "Option A", it rebuild only the webapp service.

Comment: Option A is safer. Note that I added on purpose in the `docker-compose.yml` the `dockerfile: Dockerfile` option, that allows you to specify which Dockerfile to be used in the build. You could _try/test_ a new `Dockerfile` simply by telling the docker-compose to use `Dockerfile-new-release` and if you're not happy with it, then revert to the working `Dockerfile`

Comment: Well, in respect to what you said on option B, maybe this example will make things easier to explain: if you do not change anything in any of the Dockerfiles, nothing will happen: the images will be rebuilt identically and instantly because all their layers are cached. Their hashes won't change, and the compose-up won't perform any action, evaluating both services as _up-to-date_.

Comment: Often it may happen that, we are not adding any new service, but just adding some more properties (environment, networks etc.) which were earlier not present in the same “web app”. Should we rebuild it again with the build command.